# Unable to execute Rest methods from Swagger UI and Thorntail

Tags: swagger-ui, thorntail

I have noticed that when building a Thorntail REST application using JAX-RS and Swagger UI dependencies, the REST call generated by Swagger UI  uses **https** instead of **http**.
Here is the REST Service I'm using:

```
@Path("/time")
@Api(value = "/time", description = "Get the time", tags = "time")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class HelloWorldEndpoint {

    @GET
    @Path("/now")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Get the current time",
            notes = "Returns the time as a string",
            response = String.class
    )
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String get() {
        return String.format("{\"value\" : \"The time is %s\"}", new Date());
    }
}
```

And the dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger</artifactId>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxrs</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-webapp</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

In this case, the generated REST call is:

```
curl -X GET "https://localhost:8080/time/now" -H  "accept: application/json"
```

which returns:

```
curl: (35) SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.
```

Is there any parameter (@Api ?) that forces using 'http' instead of 'https' ?

Answer (score 0):

On my side, I used this configuration in project-defaults.yml

```
thorntail:
  deployment:
    my-webapp.war:
      swagger:
        schemes:
          - http
```